Asking for known schemes
I'd like to know if it's ok to ask help in identifying schemes adapting to specified conditions.
Example:
Is there a cryptographic scheme that allows encrypted data meeting conditions A, B, C, to be sent across unsecured media and to be decrypted only if at the time of decryption the conditions are still met? Reference? Are there impossibility proofs?
Thanks for the feedback.

Sure thing, as long as it is within the rules.
Given the lack of specificity of the question: it is important to understand the basics before asking this question. Our users cannot be expected to explain cryptographic concepts to a five-year old.
These kind of questions often get closed because the asker is unable to formalize their question or indicate which cryptographic properties need to be met. If the question remains unspecific then it basically becomes a guessing game at which point no concise answer can be constructed.
At best, this situation then devolves into a vicious cycle of revising the questions and answers. Consequently, a moderator like myself may eventually be compelled to close the question because the original query and the (conceptual) answers have become misaligned.
So yes, this seems to be on-topic. But as is often the case, it is more about how to ask the questions and the basic knowledge required. I've often found myself asking a question and having it closed or getting an answer that I wasn't really able to understand.

It's worse for bounties. I'm not offering as many because I find the question interesting. The problem is that I often cannot validate the correctness of the answers given. The only thing I can then hope for is an "accept".

The questions I've read as soon as I signed up looked like everyone is a professional here. I am not; but I'd like to know if I scheme I'm devising for a project makes sense or not.
So I asked, to understand if I'm meant to be an expert that asks details of complex topics (sort of MathOverflow if you know that community) or I can be an amateur with questions of (almost) any difficulty (sort of MathStackexchange if you know that community). Ty.

Well, you can be but the important think is to try and find questions that go in your direction and pick up the language and information from them, so you can ask a more directed question yourself, (if that's still required). The current trend among especially among millennials is just to call out the question everywhere and hope for an answer, but that will result in a lot of work for everybody without too much of a reward. See Quora for what I mean, the questions and answers there are quite often horrid and focus more on a good story than on quality. Don't forget to upvote Q/A's while you do
